# Redirect with unknown URL parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, parameters

I want to grab all the "additional" parameters from a URL and put them in a `redirect_to`. I won't know what the parameters are, though.

Example: `example.com/books/1234?name=Bobby&uid=3819&gender=male`

And I'd want to do something like `redirect_to login_path(params)`

And it would then redirect to `example.com/login?name=Bobby&uid=3819&gender=male`

I know I could pass `:name`, `:uid` and `:gender` in the `redirect_to`, but like I said, I won't know exactly what parameters will be there, so I just need to grab all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you just want to pass the GET parameters to this redirect.  If so, you can do this:

```
redirect_to login_path(request.GET)
```